# What should I do if the Production editor has not responded after the proofreading process for over a month?

Tags: publications, editors

In February 2021, my paper was accepted and the proof reading process started immediately. I have returned the corrections in begin of March, but after that no sign of communication. I send 3 emails to the Production editor, without any luck. How do you recommend to continue?

---

Finally they replied and told me that they have not received my edits through the online proofing system. I have submitted everything four times and nothing is received by the other end. It is over a month since the proofreading process began and concerns only 9 edits!!! I talked with the eproofing service, but the result was the same. What do you suggest me to do? –

Comment: Hi, what you posted as an answer should actually be an update to the question. I edited it into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different email. It could be that the production editor resigned, is on leave, has been reassigned, etc. You could try the journal email, if there is one, or the publisher email, or even the editor-in-chief.

Worst case scenario, phone the publisher.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will wait few more weeks and then try to communicate. My thought was the same, that the production editor has resigned, but I will give few more days

Answer (score 0):

It's likely (or perhaps only possible) that the production staff has seen your corrections, used them and taken the next steps. I don't think I've ever heard from a journal between the time I returned proofs and the article appeared.

So not to worry. You might wait a while, then ask the editor when the paper will appear.

Comment: Thank you very much! I need to have patience and wait for few more weeks, I guess Pandemic might has affected the regular process both sides!